# MS Word does not read docx after unzip and zip

Tags: java, zip, docx, docx4j

Given ".docx" a file I
- rename it to ".zip" and unzip it into a folder
- then zip it again, and rename it back to ".docx". 
Now MS Word crashes if I try to open the new file.

This happens both performing those actions via Java code and performing them with the OS programs and tools (in MAC OS).

Can anybody explain that?

Comment: Your zip tool is probably using a compression method that MS Word doesn't support. Use the zip tool to see which compression method is use before and after.

Comment: sanity check: try unzipping again to make sure your zip didn't put everything inside a new dir that wasn't in the original zip file

Comment: Thank you @JasonPlutext .... I checked and saw that starting for example with a docx file of 38KB after unzip and zip I get back a 45KB file! Now I need to understand what compression algorithm is used to generate docx files and how to reproduce e.g. it in Java.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the filesize.  Unzip the original and your newly zipped and check you have the same filetree.  I'd sanity check that before worrying about compression.